# How to get GridView Header Text vertically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am using grid view to show data but i have many columns with big name.so it contains more screen size.

So please help me with how to get header text vertically so that column doesn't get more screen and i can show my whole grid in same page without scrolling.

I am using visual studio 2005 with vb.net

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried <br/> for each letter for header text? Please post your grid binding code if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work. Although I have to say it looks ugly AF if all the header texts are displayed vertically.

First we need a CSS class.

```
<style>
    .VerticalHeaderText {
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        width: 1px;
        //line-height needs some tweaking for font size, type etc
        line-height: 75%;
    }
</style>
```

Then we need to wrap the header texts in a container that has the class `VerticalHeaderText`. For this we use the GridViews `OnRowDataBound` event.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[i].Text = "<div class=\"VerticalHeaderText\">" + e.Row.Cells[i].Text + "</div>";
        }
    }
}
```

In VB

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header) Then
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Do While (i < e.Row.Cells.Count)
            e.Row.Cells(i).Text = ("<div class=""VerticalHeaderText"">"  _
                        + (e.Row.Cells(i).Text + "</div>"))
            i = (i + 1)
        Loop 
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but I'm curious why you used a for loop in C#, but a While loop in VB?

Comment: @Slugsie, no reason. I've put the C# code through an online code translator and this was the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
   /*Use the css on page tittle*/ 
 <style>
            .verticaltext
            {
                writing-mode: tb-rl;
                filter: flipv fliph;
            }
        </style>
    /*Call this code on gridview_Rowdatabound*/

    GridViewRow header = gv.HeaderRow;
    header.Cells[1].CssClass = "verticaltext";
```

Comment: Could you offer an explanation of your approach?