# How to display Grid View header Text Vertically?

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview

I have many columns to display in grid view. Now I am displaying Horizontally it is taking more space. so, I would like to display Vertically. I have searched a lot. I have got suggestion like use `"HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign"` attribute. And I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40415645/how-to-get-gridview-header-text-vertically) to get help from stack overflow, but it is also not working. Waiting for the priceless suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```css
div{
    transform: rotate(90deg); 
    border: thin solid #000;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div>Dummy text</div>
```